# Mysql socket error 2002 on Linux Mint - Access denied

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sockets, linux-mint

My apache and xampp servers are running on port 2145 and 16443 respectively.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.2-5...

XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
```

**Stopping it says Not running!**

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
Stopping XAMPP for Linux 1.8.2-5...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
```

I tried setting the socket path in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` as

```
 mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` points to

```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
```

`netstat -vulntp |grep -i mysql` gives me

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9789/mysqld
```

I don't see any errors in the `/var/log/mysql/error.log` except a few deprecation warnings and notes.

And **phpmyadmin was running before the system restart**.

Comment: Your mysql server is running on port 3306, not 16443

Comment: Sorry. My xampp is running on port 16443 http://localhost:16443/xampp/

Comment: @LakshmiNarayananGuptha I am having the same issue. Were to able to solve this?